# shuffle 2D array in one dimension without effecting other dimension

Tags: java, machine-learning

^no. not like that. 2D. I want to shuffle one D without changing at all the other D. plus thats about android. get that outta here.

I have a 2D array which is made up of elements:

Example:

```
Document 1 = ["I", "am", "awesome"]
Document 2 = ["I", "am", "great", "great"]
```

Dictionary is:

```
["I", "am", "awesome", "great"]
```

So the 2D array would look like:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 2]
```

What I want to do is shuffle around the location of the documents, so where we once had:

```
Document 1 = [1, 1, 1, 0]
Document 2 = [1, 1, 0, 2]
```

We now might have:

```
Document 2 = [1, 1, 0, 2]
Document 1 = [1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Or we might not. It should be shuffled randomly.

Not like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310775/how-to-shuffle-2d-array-in-java).

How to implement that?

My data structure looks like this:

```
int z = 0;
for ( Cell< int[] , String , Integer > cell: train_freq_count_against_globo_dict.cellSet() )
{              
    int[] container_of_feature_vector = cell.getRowKey();

    // 'q' CAN'T be shuffled, 'z' MUST be shuffled.
    for (int q = 0; q < globo_dict_size; q++) 
    {
        feature_matrix__train[z][q] = container_of_feature_vector[q];
     }
    // use 1 and -1 not 0 and 1
    outputs__train[z] = String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL) ? 1.0 : -1.0;

     z++;
}
```

The point of this is to implement stochastic gradient descent.

---

UPDATE:

```
  static double[][] shuffleArray(double[][] input_array)
  {  
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = input_array.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      // Simple swap
      double[] container = input_array[index];
      input_array[index] = input_array[i];
      input_array[i] = container;
    }
    return input_array;
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random shuffling of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)

Comment: @ThomasJungblut no, not the same. i want to just shuffle the 1D without effecting the other D

Comment: works exactly the same way.

Comment: @Herr Thomas, like that? in update.

Comment: Yep, exactly like that. Please post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Herr Thomas, I just ran it and the F1 was sonder low, i think actually that's not the right way

Comment: There is no guarantee that randomization will give you a better f1 score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this!

But don't take my word for it, use `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(input_array));` and verify that result yourself. science.

```
  static double[][] shuffleArray(double[][] input_array)
  {  
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = input_array.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      // Simple swap
      double[] container = input_array[index];
      input_array[index] = input_array[i];
      input_array[i] = container;
    }
    return input_array;
  }
```